# Configuring a SQL Server (2008) Monitor Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, monitoring

After having a period of logshipping failures going unnoticed (due to a stopped SQL Agent on the secondary server) I'm looking at configuring some monitoring.

Having seen the ability to specify a "Monitor Server instance" on the SQL Server 2008 log shipping setup and the relavant MSDN docs (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510705.aspx), I'm keen to setup a "Monitor Server". However having trawled MSDN and google I actually can't find any information on how to configure a Monitor Server.

At this point I don't even know what a monitor server is (i.e. is it just another SQL Server instance?)! Also, is this separate from the monitoring modules in SQL Server Management Studio?

Any guidance or pointers to documentation would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The log shipping monitor is a third server that watches the primary and standby servers and keeps a log of the backups, copies and restores so you can find out what's going on. The benefit of using a monitor is that you still know your status even if one or both of the participating servers goes down. For instance, if the primary server goes down you know how much data you will lose if you fail over to the standby server.

I'm pretty sure you can add a monitor to your existing log shipping setup. This article should help you learn more:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190640.aspx

Comment: You cannot add a monitor to an existing setup, you must do it when configuring log shipping: "To monitor this log shipping configuration, you must add the monitor server now. To add the monitor server later, you would need to remove this log shipping configuration and then replace it with a new configuration that includes a monitor server."

Answer (score 0):

Well the monitor in the sql server what bee see is this [Monitor](http://geeks.ms/blogs/jalarcon/archive/2009/07/31/191-d-243-nde-est-225-el-monitor-de-actividad-en-sql-server-2009.aspx) in [English](http://blogs.msdn.com/billramo/archive/2008/12/27/where-is-that-darn-activity-monitor-in-sql-server-2008.aspx), I don't know if i'm right but for me the SQL Monitor is not an Instance, is a Module, and in this post explains what happend with the monitor in the last [release](http://news.softpedia.com/news/SQL-Server-2008-Activity-Monitor-100945.shtml), i hoppe this information helps you, and how to configurate i found this information only for the options [Activity Monitor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc879320.aspx)

See you

Comment: Activity Monitor is an unrelated feature of SQL Server Management studio. I'm more interested in the remote monitoring of several sql server instances for things like Transaction Logging, Mirroring etc

Comment: You Can try with the SQL Profiler may can help you.